# How desplay the number from the Code in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Show only the variable number in the blade from the `$sum` value

In Blade:

```
{{$sum}}
```

In controller:

```
$sum = OrderPosition::select(DB::raw('sum(quantity*product_price) AS total_sales'))->where('quantity', '<>', 1)->get();
```

the output is `{"total_sales":"550.00"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display the object. Try this in blade

```
{{$sum->total_sales}}
```

Comment: I have been replaced get() with first() 
After that I added the {{$sum->total_sales}}
 to the blade.  successfully done thanks